# Menu block goes crazy after 4th level

Tags: routes

When I click on a 4th level link of a Menu block, the 3rd level disappear.
This is the menu:

- Services
- - Accommodation
- - - Building A
- - - - Apartment 1
- - - - Apartment 2

I have 3 blocks to show this menu:

1. 1st level block (Starting level 1st, max depth 1): is ok
2. 2nd level block (Starting level 2nd, max depth 1): is ok
3. 3rd level+ block (Starting level 3rd, max depth 9): it's not ok

When I click on a third level link (Building A) the 3rd block shows:

- Accommodation
- - **Building A**
- - - Apartment 1
- - - Apartment 2

but when I click on any 4th level links (i.e. Apartment 1), the 2nd level link disappears and it shows:

- Building A
- - **Apartment 1**
- - Apartment 2

I need to see the third level links even if I click on the 4th+ levels. What I need is this:

- Accommodation
- - Building A
- - - **Apartment 1**
- - - Apartment 2

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
In the menu block configuration, **Advanced Options**, I checked **Make the starting level follow the active menu item**.